Two problems with all Stack Exchange sites

I am unable to see the avatars of many (but not all) users, including my own. A broken image icon is shown instead. Some avatars (both autogenerated and user-uploaded) are shown normally. I have tried to re-upload my picture, but it didn't help.
Every now and then after a period of inactivity, the system starts to doubt whether I'm human. When I hit any link, or just reload a page, I might see a screen that says something like "Verifying you are human" and a spinning circle. Then the check apparently succeeds without any action on my part. It takes a couple of seconds each time. In these periods of doubt, menus and other similar elements on the page (for example the mailbox icon at the top right) do not work, I see a "Something went wrong, please try again" message. I have to reload the page (and see the human check screen) to make them work again.

I suspect these two things might be somehow related.

I doubt they're related. The former sounds like something on your end - something preventing the images from resolving/loading due to a blocker or your location (you can test this by using a "clean" browser and accessing the site with a VPN). The second issue is pretty normal. There are certain things that will cause the system to return a human test - even just starting a question/answer draft one day and finishing it the next. The current human checks actually don't give you a "test" unless they actually think you're not - that's normal.

Here's info about the "No CATPCHA reCAPTCHA" - https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha

@Catija (1) Are different avatars served from different network locations? (2) This "captcha" happens every 5 minites or so lately, and interferes with normal functioning of all SE sites.

As far as I'm aware, yes. They come from different sources - the avatars can be sourced from Google, Facebook, Gravatar, or locally - I think. I don't think they're all hosted on SE directly. For example, this user's avatar is from Google - https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1603455/amin

@Catija it is CloudFlare blocking or rate limiting users, we get more and more reports about this since SE switched to use them, and these days they are tightening security, so it's only getting much worse. They keep saying ordinary users are "not supposed" to be affected, but looks like it's not really true. If I was in charge, I would ditch CloudFlare and find a CDN that don't block so many people, even in the cost of having to work harder to block the actual bad traffic.

@Catija you are probably right on problem 1, I don't see avatars on the corporate network, but I do see them on my home network. Specifically I don't see those hosted on i.sstatic.net. I don't know which side is blocking which though.

If you open the broken avatar images in a tab, what you do see? (right click, open image in new tab)

@RyanM I can't, there's no menu option to open a broken image. But I looked at the URL on my home computer (where I can see the image) and tried to wget it from a work computer. The wget command just hanged on "Connecting to..." message. I also don't seem to get the human verification message at home. So it is really a problem with my corporate network. Somebody is blocking somebody.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Might not be blocked, just might be broken on the other end, or the image isn’t yet available on whatever copy of the CDN the “broken” network routes you to. A different issue but for a long time now, I have been unable to see any Facebook-based avatar, doesn’t matter where I’m trying from. Maybe the googleuser ones too.
